# How do I create a child element within a Nokogiri node?

Tags: ruby, xml, ruby-on-rails-4, nokogiri, children

I’m using Rails 4.2.7 with Nokogiri.  I’m having trouble creating a child node.  I have the following code

```
general = doc.xpath("//lomimscc:general")
description = Nokogiri::XML::Node.new "lomimscc:description", doc
string = Nokogiri::XML::Node.new "lomimscc:string", doc
string.content = scenario.abstract
string['language'] = 'en'
description << string
general << description
```

I want the “description” element to be a child element of the “general” element (and similarly I want the “string” element to be a child of the “description” element).  However what is happening is that the description element is appearing as a sibling of the general element.  How do I make the element appear as a child instead of a sibling?

Comment: Read "[mcve]". What is the minimal XML that demonstrates the problem?

Answer (score 8):

The tutorials show how to do this in "[Creating new nodes](https://nokogiri.org/tutorials/modifying_an_html_xml_document.html#creating-new-nodes)", but the simple example is:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::XML('<root/>')
doc.at('root').add_child('<foo/>')
doc.to_xml # => "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>\n<root>\n  <foo/>\n</root>\n"
```

Nokogiri makes it easy to build nodes using a string that contains the markup or nodes you want to add.

You should be able to build upon this easily.

This is also noted throughout the [Node](https://nokogiri.org/rdoc/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html) documentation any place you see "`node_or_tags`".

Comment: The tutorials actually don't state this (as of today)

Comment: @JulianC Still works though as mentioned in documentation https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/nokogiri/Nokogiri/XML/Document#add_child-instance_method

Comment: Read "[Creating new nodes](https://nokogiri.org/tutorials/modifying_an_html_xml_document.html#creating-new-nodes)", which does show the use of a string literal containing the markup.

Answer (score -1):

When I changed

```
general = doc.xpath("//lomimscc:general")
```

to

```
general = doc.xpath("//lomimscc:general").first
```

then everything worked as far as creating child nodes.